# accessing scope variable in ng-template witin ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to show dynamically changing variables in a dialog box using idialog. I have to use idialog in ng-repeat but it is not working.

The code for ng-repeat:

```
            <tr ng-repeat="history in historyDetails track by $index| orderBy:sortType:sortReverse| filter:searchSproc">
            <td class="ui-helper-center">
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="history">
                    <font color="black"><h1>Details</h1></font>
                    <br />

                    <font color="black">
                       {{history.SprocInputs}}
                    </font>
                </script>
                <a idialog="history"  title="INPUTS  : &#013; {{history.SprocInputs}} &#013;&#013; OUTPUT : &#013; {{history.SprocOutputs}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" tooltip><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign "</a>


            </td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.ApplicationName }}</td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.SprocName }}</td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.ExecutedDate }}</td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.RPD }}</td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.Comments }}</td>
            <td class="ui-helper-center">{{ history.ExecutedBy }}</td>
        </tr>
```

When i click on the image it gives me a dialog showing just details and not the expression.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Why don't you use `directive` for dom manipulation ?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Use a directive instead of ng-template, it's much better suited for what you are trying to do.